# if else with || (or) operator didn't work in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

i have an if else statement and if the expression has not value or another value then i push this value to an object. Let me show you:

```
const checkProps = [];
if (currentOasis !== undefined) {
      checkProps.push(`currentOasis=${currentOasis}`);
    }
    if (decimalShow !== undefined) || (decimalShow !== false)  {
      checkProps.push(`decimalShow=${decimalShow}`);
    }
```

The decimalShow value is in my case undefined but when i console.log the checkprops array has decimalShow=undefined. Why is this happening?

Comment: Does your code parse?

Comment: undefined should be string `'undefined'`

Comment: First fix the syntax errors

Comment: If a value is `undefined` the first part of the or will be false, but the second part will still be true `undefined !== false`

Comment: No i dont think so, if i use single if without the || operator it works. Undefined is a keyword in javascript not a string

Comment: @user7334203 Please first thing to do : **open your console**

Comment: *"If it's not undefined __or__ not false…"* – Well, so if it's `undefined`, then it's not `false`, condition is true. If it's `false`, then it's not `undefined`, condition is true. If it's anything else, the condition it true. **The condition is always true.** You have a simple logic error. You want the `&&` operator, not `||`.

Comment: @zedling Only if you also throw in the `typeof` operator; just by itself `undefined` doesn't compare to `'undefined'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your condition is always true.** If the value is `undefined`, then it's not `false`. If it's `false`, then it's not `undefined`. If it's anything else, it's not either. And the test always passes.

If you want to filter those two values, you need an `&&` condition:

```
if (decimalShow !== undefined && decimalShow !== false) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Putting if like this

```
if ((decimalShow !== undefined) || (decimalShow !== false)) {
  checkProps.push(decimalShow=${decimalShow}); 
}
```

because the syntax for if is `if(condition){}`

You missed the parenthesis.

Comment: not quite, see my comment above. It should be `&&`

Comment: I tried this before but it didnt work